# visual studio 2015 cordova app and script inline for android

Tags: javascript, android, inline

I've got a problem with the inline scripts on android emulator, they don't want to work.
I've already solved with the addeventlistener but now I need to add some old code and I don't want to rewrite every inline event.
Is it possible to adapt inline events for android too?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```